# How can I link Firebase auth Android app and web app?

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have two projects a web app and an Android app and I want to link them together. I have Firebase auth set up on the Android app (user app) and I want the admin web application to link the auth account as 2 way (admin and user). Is that possible? If it is, can you explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible?

For sure it's possible. This can be simply done inside the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/). Once you have successfully created your project, then you'll be able to add as many apps as you need. Since you have a web and an Android app, you should go to "Project settings" and hit the blue <kbd>Add app</kbd> button. The first time you should create the web app and the second time, the Android app. How? Simply follow the instructions that are provided. There are only 2 steps in the case of a web app, and four in the case of an Android app.